# EBADCSRFTOKEN: Invalid CSRF token in adonis js

Tags: vue.js, adonis.js

I am getting `EBADCSRFTOKEN: Invalid CSRF token` while trying to use ivew Ui upload components. Tried to set header like this

`this.headerCsrf['X-XSRF-TOKEN'] = document.cookie.split("XSRF-TOKEN=")[1]`

It add the header with the key `X-XSRF-TOKEN` but still I get this error. Help please. I am using adonuxt..

Answer (score 0):

I can not guess the context from your call to you controller. But my headers are correctly sent using AJAX in the following format:

```
headers: {'x-csrf-token': $('[name=_csrf]').val()},
```

Alternatively, you can disable CSRF auth in the **config/shield.js** file, at the bottom just turn to false the enable variable, like this:

```
 csrf: {
    enable: false,
    methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'],
    filterUris: [],
    cookieOptions: {
      httpOnly: false,
      sameSite: true,
      path: '/',
      maxAge: 7200
    }
  }
```

Comment: Disabling csrf is not a good idea..  How can I use the above code in plain js?

Comment: my answer is regarding an Ajax call with jquery and I works

Answer (score 0):

you can add your route path in filterUris like this

```
csrf: {
enable: true,
methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'],
filterUris: ['/firstroute','*',],
cookieOptions: {
  httpOnly: false,
  sameSite: true,
  path: '/',
  maxAge: 7200
}
```

}

more info about this check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57452122/adonisjs-error-code-ebadcsrftoken-in-postman-in-put-post-delete-operation/57483896?noredirect=1#comment101681089_57483896)