# AdonisJS Error Code "EBADCSRFTOKEN" in Postman in PUT,POST,DELETE operation

Tags: adonis.js

I have created REST API in AdoniJs. In this I have created API endpoints for CRUD operations with GET, POST, PUT and DELETE menthods. I am using `shieldjs` as a middleware to verify `CSRF` token. I am making API calls from Postman.

Firstly I am calling GET method of API and I am getting the expected data properly and 3 cookies as part of response, out of which, one is `XSRF-TOKEN`.

But when I am calling PUT, POST and DELETE methods by setting key `X-XSRF-TOKEN` to the value of `XSRF-TOKEN` from the cookie in request header, I am getting error `EBADCSRFTOKEN` as response in Postman.

Configuration of `CSRF` in ShieldJS in `shield.js` file

```
csrf: {
    enable: true,
    methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'],
    filterUris: [],
    cookieOptions: {
      httpOnly: false,
      sameSite: true,
      path: '/',
      maxAge: 7200
    }
}
```

Code of Error Handler in `handler.js` file

```
async handle (error, {request, response }) {
    if (error.code === 'EBADCSRFTOKEN') {
        response.forbidden(error.code)
        return
    }
}
```

When I am changing value of `enable: false` for `csrf` in ShieldJs then its working fine but after I do `enable: true` I am getting the error `EBADCSRFTOKEN`.

I should not get this error code as I am sending `xsrf` token.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Put **filterUris** in your route path like this

```
csrf: {
    enable: true,
    methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'],
    filterUris: ['/firstroute','*',],
    cookieOptions: {
      httpOnly: false,
      sameSite: true,
      path: '/',
      maxAge: 7200
    }
  }
```

More read about csrf visit this website [adonisjs](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/csrf#sponsor)

---

#### Second way is

- Create REST API project. when creating API then not need a view. This error generates when not getting csrftoken. 
  So you can try to create a project for the only API not include view like this 
  `adonis new projectname --api-only`

More info follow this [link](http://'https://github.com/adonisjs/adonis-api-app') how to create an API project.

Comment: I tried your solution. Added `filterUris: ['/users/:id', '/users',]` and now my application is working as desired. Thanks.